# Flutter ARB localization throws "the getter was called on null" error

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

Following the tips of the [official internationalization tutorial](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#adding-your-own-localized-messages) I am getting the `The getter was called on null` when trying to use the autogenerated from ARB files translation engine (`AppLocalizations.of(context).helloWrold`):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';

class Login extends StatelessWidget {
  final loginAction;
  final String loginError;

  const Login(this.loginAction, this.loginError);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            loginAction();
          },
          child: Text(AppLocalizations.of(context).helloWorld),
        ),
        Text(loginError ?? ''),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution to this problem is a missing part of the official tutorial. It is not described there that to allow the engine to function, one needs to declare additional delegate in the `main.dart` file. This can be concluded out of the [example GitHub repository](https://github.com/flutter/website/blob/a10683f0e3f1e83544e3d0b30c8fabd6ca679a04/examples/internationalization/gen_l10n_example/lib/main.dart#L15). To fix the issue, go to the `MaterialApp` and add the missing delegate `AppLocalizations.delegate`:

```
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';


      child: MaterialApp(
          localizationsDelegates: [
            // ... app-specific localization delegate[s] here
            AppLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
            GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          supportedLocales: [
            const Locale('en', ''),
            const Locale('pl', '')
          ],
          home: Scaffold(
```